# Manage routes with Slim framework and MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, slim

It seems that there is a conflict between MAMP and Slim framework on my environment.
I am trying to learn Slim, and I have this weird situation where I can create a route for '/', but impossible to do it for '/contact'.

```
$app->get('/', \App\Controllers\PagesController::class . ':home');
$app->get('/contact', \App\Controllers\PagesController::class . ':getContact');
```

Slim seems to catch the / route, but when I type http://localhost:8888/contact/ in my browser Slim doesn't catch the request, I have a 404...

I tried to create a real "contact" folder with an index.html file inside, and of course then it works... it displays the index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to route all requests to the `index.php` file. Mamp is looking for a directory structure that does not exist until you create it, as you did.

Create a `.htaccess` file in the your app's root folder. and insert the following:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

if you are just learning php and slim then I recommend ditching MAMP and just using the integrated PHP server. From your project's folder, Kick off the server with the following CLI command:
`PHP -S localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I also run a mysql server the same way?

Comment: You mostly use the built in PHP server in the case you don't need to practice on a mysql server.

Comment: You mean I can access a mysql DB (via PhpMyAdmin for example) built in the integrated PHP server?

Comment: Theoretically yes you can, but you would have to install the PhpMyAdmin script and configure it to access a standalone mysqlDB. The PHP integrated server is single threaded, which means it will choke at some point. It's not designed for heavy loads.